# Is it possible to have clustering based on multiple string features

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am trying to learn and understand how clustering algorithms work using Python

**Question:**

I have a dataset with about say 5 columns with mix data types(alphanumeric/date/numeric), and I want to cluster it based on multiple fields with common value.

**Example:**

```
Index  Col-1       Col-2       Col-3       Col-4         Col-5    
----------------------------------------------------------------
 0     US1          John        ABC123      01/01/2019    200
 1     US2          Alex        256xyz      01/12/2018    8000
 2     US1          John        ABC12       01/01/2019    200
 3     US2          Alex        00256xyz    01/12/2018    8000
 4     US2          Alex        XYZ         01/12/2018    8000
 5     US3          Mary        345abc      27/03/2000    9040
```

**Output:**

```
                Index

Cluster-1:     0 and 2

Cluster-2:       1,3,4

Cluster-3:      5
```

Based on Col-1,2,4,5 clusters should be created.

I don't know if that makes any sense and if it is possible to achieve it.

If yes, what would be the best algorithm to use for non-numeric dataset? Or it can be achieved through code.

Comment: as per the example seems like you want to group by based on col-1 value ?

Comment: No, based on col1,col2,col 4, col5 all four columns. Not sure if its possible.

Comment: @user12277274 i am also facing a similar scenario. Were you able to do it by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for an exact match or clustering with approximate matching. 
For exact match you can simply group by all four columns to create a group_id for each combination and then find all those who belong to same group by joining with this table.

In case of approximate matching you can either encode them as dummy variables and use hamming distance to compute similarity and create clusters based on it